# Google drive web page halts when loading

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-drive

When loading the Google drive [page](https://drive.google.com), the page halts after displaying a `loading...` message in the title. This issue is not resolved [on the Google-drive forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/vbYi4OGRnKk).

See screenshots below.

Sometimes after a couple of minutes I get a message on the page that I should clear my browser's cache.

This happens in Chrome and Firefox, but I haven't encountered the problem in Explorer.

The OS is Windows 7. Chrome is up-to-date.

Temporary remedies that I have found:

- Clearing the cache sometimes helps for a while, but the problem comes back.
- Going the Chrome->Tools->Task manager, and closing the Google Drive task helps, but the problem comes back.

Re-installing Chrome didn't help.

Found these screenshots in the google forum (not mine):
[image: A screenshot I found in the google forums]
[image: A screenshot I found in the google forums]

Comment: Do you have a Web security or parental control installed such as Kaspersky? If yes, please turn it off and try again.

Comment: You have your notification areas turned off so its hard to tell.  Typically this is when you will see "waiting for ..." where ... is some resource that gets miscached in your router or ISP.  A typical offender is pagead2.google.com, google-analytics.com or platform.twitter.com or some CDN hosted javascript resource.  I hacked together something for myself here: http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=82639

Comment: @harrymc, No Web Security, no Kaspersky.

Comment: @technosaurus, wouldn't these problems occur in my Internet Explorer? But in IE it works fine.

Comment: @harrymc I have same problems on new PCs and notebooks with clean, just installed Windowses and fresh firefoxes with new profiles, and the same is on several-years-old PC with auto-updated firefoxes on them. I almost don't use firefox myself, but I've seen this behavior for at many users, and it appeared with either some Google services change, or some Firefox update.

Answer (score 4):

You have Adblock installed in Chrome, and probably in Firefox as well. It is known to cause problems with Google [Drive](http://www.google.com/search?q=adblock+"google+drive%22+loading) and [Docs](http://www.google.com/search?q=adblock+"google+docs") (and possibly other Google sites).

The problem is that because Google built its (vast) fortune on advertising, it is certainly not amenable to ad-blockers of any kind. There have been [complaints](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/g-xZWarRnos) that it no longer works on Google sites and that [Adblock breaks Google sites](http://support.getadblock.com/discussions/problems/312-adblock-breaks-google-docs-and-spreadsheets-etc-color-picker), [reports](http://googlesystem.blogspot.ca/2013/11/google-adblock-exception.html) that Google tells users to exclude Google sites, [accusations](http://www.theverge.com/2013/7/5/4496852/adblock-plus-eye-google-whitelist) that Google paid Adblock to white-list their sites, and even [warnings](http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/1a9y5h/google_has_removed_adblock_plus_from_the_play/) that Google is [removing](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/03/13/breaking-google-has-begun-purging-ad-blocking-apps-from-the-play-store/) ad-blockers from its webstores (which really benefits them since they are also going to [block](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html) users from installing extensions outside of the webstore).

It would not be a surprise if Google had updated some of its sites so that they no longer work correctly if Adblock is installed. Disabling Adblock should fix the problem. You can try adding Google Docs/Drive to Adblock’s white-list so that you can keep using Adblock *and* Google sites, but turning Adblock on still breaks Google sites even with them added to the white-list, then Google may have made changes that prevent Adblock from working on their sites, in which case, you have a tough choice to make.

Comment: Great. How?​​​​

Comment: Oh okay. Glad it worked. Did you try white-listing Google to see if you can keep using Adblock with other sites?

Comment: Disabling AdBlock by itself isn't enough. Disabling AdBlock + clearing the browser's cache seems to work.

Comment: Well yes, you should always clear the cache. If AdBlock had prevented Chrome from downloading some files, then you’ll need to make sure it does so next time, and the best way to ensure that happens is to clear the cache so that it has to re-download *everything*. But did you try white-listing?

Comment: I'll try white listing when the problem returns. It may take more than a day.

Comment: Hopefully it will work and you can use both. (Though Adblock’s time may be limited if Google gets its way.)

Comment: What seems to work: go to the url, click on the AdBlock icon, select "don't run on this page".

Comment: Yes, that’s the white-list I said. If it works, then you can keep using AdBlock and Google Drive. (To block Google ads, you can try different ad-blocking methods outside the browser.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix the problem be if you use [this code](https://superuser.com/questions/509063/how-to-delete-chrome-temp-data-history-cookies-cache-using-command-line) and add it to start up it will clear your chrome cache every time you start your computer. And as you have said clearing chrome cache helps.

Answer (score 0):

The page
[Drive.google.com - Is Google Drive Down Right Now?](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/drive.google.com.html)
contains complaints about Google Drive from all along the year 2013.

That server pings Google Drive every day and displays the status for the last 10 days.
Its current status message says
"Drive.google.com is UP and reachable. The website is probably down just for you...".

Nonetheless, the page contains this advice :

> If the site is UP but you can't access the page, try one of the below
>   solutions:
>
> **Browser Related Problems**
>
> - Force a full refresh for the site. This can be achieved by pressing    CTRL + F5 keys at the same time on your favourite browser (Firefox, Chrome, Explorer, etc.)
> - Try alternative urls such as googledrive.com
> - Clear the temporary cache and cookies on your browser to make sure that you have the most recent version of the web page.
>
> **Fix DNS Problems**
>
> A Domain Name System (DNS) allows a site IP address (192.168.x.x) to
>   be identified with words (*.com) in order to be remembered more
>   easily, like a phonebook for websites. This service is usually
>   provided by your ISP.
>
> - Clear your local DNS cache to make sure that you grab the most recent cache that your ISP has. For Windows - (Start > Command Prompt > type "ipconfig /flushdns" and hit enter).
> - If you can access a website at office or from a 3G network yet it's    not working on your computer, it is a good idea to use an alternative 
>     DNS service other than your ISP. OpenDNS or Google Public DNS are
>     both excellent and free public DNS services.

The above page contains links to step-by-step instructions on how to implement
the above advice.

I also remark that the Web is full of complaints about Google Drive.
Some found out that the message is correct and that the page is not blocked but
really loading, just being extremely slow about it (up to several hours!).
Others solved the problem by moving to Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

In short, disable/configure AdBlock and clear the browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

**Multifox can be the reason.** If you use the [Multifox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multifox/) for Firefox and choose any Multifox profile except "Default Profile", that is the reason why Google Drive gets stuck loading. This is a useful extension that enabled multiple parallel logins on the same site, and works with nearly all sites. But since around August 2016, no longer with Google Drive. Simple choose "Default Profile" from the Multifox menu and Google Drive will work fine again.

**Diagnostics.** Multifox gives a relatively hidden hint about this issue: When in a non-default profile, the Multifox menu becomes an "X" on red background, and now contains "Show Error" as last menu item. Clicking it will show an error message like:

> This page may not work with a Multifox profile because it uses a feature not supported (indexedDB).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing extensions related to Google Drive (Drive, Docs, Sheets etc.). For me on Windows 10, doing this in Chrome cured the problem I had in Chrome, IE and Edge: the left and right sidebars were loading, but the main area just showed the coloured spinner.

On Chrome: click the three vertical dots at the top right (or press and release Alt then space) to open the menu, and choose More Tools | Extensions. Press the trash can to the right of each Google Drive-related extension.